# Django CMS manage placeholder in template pages

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I would enjoy your help on two points :

First, I am creating some default page's templates like :
"Home.html, work-with-us.html" etc.

My aim is to simplify the work of people who will be in charge of the website. They don't have to learn how to manage plugin inside placeholder.

Thus, I created some placeholder like this , example for "workwithus.html" :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        {% placeholder "image-full" %}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        {% placeholder "text-platform" %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

And I managed the plugins this way :

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
'image-full': {
    'plugins': ['FilerImagePlugin'],
    'name': gettext("Image full page"),
    'default_plugins': [
        {
            'plugin_type': 'FilerImagePlugin',
            'values': {
            },
        },
    ],
    'limits': {
        'global': 1,
        'FilerImagePlugin': 1,
    },
},
```

etc

The problem is that, I can't use multiple time the same placeholder in the same template. It would be so nice if, when I make a placeholder "img-full-width" I could be able to call it several times.
Do you have any idea about it ? A way to make it more proper than creating "img-full-2", "img-full-3" etc.

Second question :
Is it possible to add more than one default_plugins ? It really annoy me...

Thank you very much in advance guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many plugins as you like as `default_plugins`

See http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/support-3.0.x/reference/configuration.html#placeholder-default-plugins

> You can specify the **list** of default plugins which will be
>   automagically added when the placeholder will be created (or
>   rendered).

If you are annoyed with having to redefine `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` for each placeholder, you can always define a common config before the `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` block:

```
img_fullwidth_conf = {
    'plugins': ['FilerImagePlugin', 'TextPlugin'],
    'name': gettext("Image full page"),
    'default_plugins': [
        {
            'plugin_type': 'FilerImagePlugin',
            'values': {
            },
        },
        {
            'plugin_type': 'TextPlugin',
            'values': {
                'body': '<p>Write here...</p>'
            },
        },
    ],
}

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'img-full-1': img_fullwidth_conf,
    'img-full-2': img_fullwidth_conf,
    'img-full-3': img_fullwidth_conf,

}
```

Comment: Strange, I did it for multiple default but it didn't work. I must have done a typo, I will try again.
I appreciate the tips for the CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF !
Thank you very much sir !